# Фильтрация arr по arguments

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять, почему функция destroyer возвращает arr без первого элемента. Ведь arguments[1] = 2. Следовательно фильтрация должна идти по 2?

```
function destroyer(arr) {
   function checkVal() {
    return arguments[1];
  }
  return arr.filter(checkVal);
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Comment: `arguments` функции `checkVal` не имеет никакого отношения к `arguments` функции `destroyer`, это разные `arguments`

Comment: Спасибо, понял!

Answer (score 1):

Каждая новая функция получает свой личный `arguments`.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Если ответ решил Вашу проблему, пожалуйста, примите его (галочка слева от ответа). Ну и плюс, если сильно помог :)